# failed to load bundle react native after I change project path

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bundle

I have copied react native project to other directory and run

```
react-native run-ios
```

And it show this error screen.
I tried as they recommended but it doesn't work.
I restored project path to original.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. You can copied react native project to other directory and you need to delete both ios,android and node module folder. Run the following commands
2. > npm install //to get the node module folder
3. > react-native upgrade //to get android and ios folder
4. > react-native link // for linking the libraries
5. > react-native run ios